# Get address of main() function under Debug Build

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to get address of main() function in this way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   void *pMainAddress=(void *)&main;
   printf("Address of main() 0x%08X \n", pMainAddress);
```

When I build project using *Release* configuration, the result is:
Address of main() : `0x00401000`

This is under debugger:

```
00401000  /$  68 00104000  PUSH GetMain.00401000    ;  Entry address
00401005  |.  68 50A14000  PUSH GetMain.0040A150    ;  ASCII "0x%p \n"
0040100A  |.  E8 8B000000  CALL GetMain.0040109A
```

But when compiling with */Zi* option, or use *Debug* build, address is redirected:
Address of main() : `0x0041178A`. 
This address is obtained by performing an [unconditional jump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_%28x86_instruction%29), the actual address is `0x00412530`

This is under debugger:

```
00412530  /> \55                      PUSH EBP
...
00412539  |.  C745 FC 8A174100        MOV [LOCAL.1],GetMain.0041178A  ;  Entry address
00412540  |.  8B45 FC                 MOV EAX,[LOCAL.1]
00412543  |.  50                      PUSH EAX                                                         
00412544  |.  68 5CEC4200             PUSH GetMain.0042EC5C           ;  ASCII "0x%p \n"
```

Why this hapenes ?
How to get the real address of main() function (`0x00412530` in above example) if code is compiled in Debug build ?

**Edit:**
Why this happens ? is already answered  here: [strange level of indirection of a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221855/strange-level-of-indirection-of-a-function-call)

Function below solve my second question, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093159/1014003) I wrote answer .

```
void *GetMainAddress(void)
{
    void *pMainAddress=(void*)&main;/* address in main() function */
    unsigned long calculateJump=0;
    unsigned char *ptrJump;   
    printf("Address of main() : 0x%08X\n",  pMainAddress);


    ptrJump=(unsigned char*)pMainAddress;/* get pointer to main address */
    if(*(unsigned char*)ptrJump == 0xE9)/* address point to jmp opcode ? */
    {
        calculateJump = ( *(unsigned long *)(ptrJump+1) ); /* get address after 0xe9 */
        pMainAddress =  ptrJump + calculateJump + 5; /* calculate real address */
        printf("Unconditional jump is performed\n");
        printf("Actual sddress of main() is: 0x%08X \n", pMainAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unconditional jump is not performed\n");
    }
    return   pMainAddress;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange level of indirection of a function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221855/strange-level-of-indirection-of-a-function-call)

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that in C++, unlike C, `main()` cannot be called recursively and cannot have its address taken. Be careful if mixing C and C++ code or compiler (although there are tons of other differences so mixing is no good anyway).

Comment: @VladLazarenko Lazarenko You're right, but in my case I do not call `main()`, only take the pointer to its address.
When code is compiled with `/ZI`, `pMainAddress` is a pointer to a jump opcode, otherwise (*Release Build*) - it is the actual address of `main()`
Also, I tested it before posting and it working in both language C and C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit the parentheses if you need to get a function address.

For example:

```
int main(){
    printf("main is at %p\n", main);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you shouldn't be using `%p` to print a function pointer.

Comment: Why not? It doesn't seem it makes any difference between %p and %x.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.  It almost certainly works on any reasonable machine, though.  Relevant reading:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741683/how-to-format-a-function-pointer

Comment: According to the C standard, function pointers do not have to be compatible with any object pointer type (including `void *`), so `void *pMainAddress=&main;` would be undefined behavior. POSIX.1, however, mandates that conversion of a function pointer to/from `void *` must work correctly. **Note, however**, that if you're trying to pass a function pointer to something like [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), however, you **must** cast the pointer to `void *`.

Comment: The reason you should be using `%p` instead of `%x` when printing a pointer is that the `%p` conversion specifier is explicitly provided for the purpose of printing pointers, whereas `%x` is intended for the printing of `unsigned int` objects. On a 64-bit system there's every chance that a pointer will be twice as large as an `unsigned int` object, and this results in Undefined Behavior, because you'll be passing a 64-bit object to a variadic function that's only expecting 32 bits. (While UB really does mean "no guarantees", one likely result is that you'll only be printing half the pointer.)

Comment: @boleto, that's what I said.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution how to get the actual address of `main()` function when [Debug Information Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx) is set to `/ZI` in the project configuration on Visual Studio.
Here is my function :

```
void *GetMainAddress(void)
{
    void* pMainAddress = (void*)&main;
    unsigned long calculateJump = 0;
    unsigned char* ptrJump;

    ptrJump = (unsigned char*)pMainAddress;
    if(*(unsigned char*)ptrJump == 0xE9)
    {
        calculateJump = (*(unsigned long*)(ptrJump + 1));
        pMainAddress = (ptrJump + calculateJump + 5);
        printf("Unconditional jump is performed\n");
        printf("Address of main() : %#x \n", pMainAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unconditional jump is not performed\n");
        printf("Address of main() : %#x \n", pMainAddress);     
    }
    return   pMainAddress;
}
```

To test, use Visual Studio to create *Console Applications* and choose either `Debug` or `Release` from the Solution Configurations.
Place the `GetAddressOfMain()` in your `int main()`, and build solution .

Function also works with 64-bit project configuration, but you need to use an appropriate format specifier to print the addresses correctly .